# How to update my UseEffect component to render new UI after a successful user login

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, use-effect, use-state

I have a login component that after the user have login, I went ahead to get the data to my local storage and if the login is successeful, which means the data is true, I want to update my component by redirecting the user another components and update my component with the user information. Right now the login went successfully and data been passed to the local storage, but, I don't get redirected, because in the next componet, the update is not happening. and in my console logs waning error that said "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

here is my login component

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

const applicationForm = {
  firstname: "",
  lastname: "",
  middlename: "",
  gender: "",
  dob: "",
  phone: "",
  email: "",
  country: "",
  crr_state: "",
  institution: "",
  fac_dept: "",
  year_entry: "",
  matric_number: "",
  student_status: "",
  edu_level: "",
  applying_as: "",
  team_members: "",
  idea_grant: "",
  category: "",
  current_status: "",
  area_of_interest: "",
  formStatus: "Save and Continur later",
  id: user ? user._id : "",
  idea_summary: "",
  video_url: "",
  textChange: "Sumbit",
};

const NUICAppForm = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(applicationForm);
  const [states, setStates] = useState(null);

  const categoryList = [
    "Renewable Energy Technologies",
    "Satellite Communication Technologies",
    "Drone Technologies",
    "E-commerce Development",
    "Smart AgricTech",
    "Mobile Computing and 5G Networks",
  ];

  const {
    firstname,
    lastname,
    middlename,
    gender,
    dob,
    phone,
    email,
    country,
    crr_state,
    institution,
    fac_dept,
    year_entry,
    matric_number,
    student_status,
    edu_level,
    current_status,
    applying_as,
    team_members: {
      memberFullname1,
      memberEmail1,
      memberPhone1,
      memberFullname2,
      memberEmail2,
      memberPhone2,
      memberFullname3,
      memberEmail3,
      memberPhone3,
      memberFullname4,
      memberEmail4,
      memberPhone4,
      memberFullname5,
      memberEmail5,
      memberPhone5,
    },
    idea_grant,
    category,
    area_of_interest,
    idea_summary,
    video_url,
    formStatus,
    id,
    textChange,
  } = formData;

  const clear = () => {
    window.localStorage.clear();
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormData({ ...formData, textChange: "Submitting" });
    axios
      .post("https://i-next-backend.herokuapp.com/nuic/form/register", {
        firstname,
        lastname,
        middlename,
        gender,
        dob,
        phone,
        email,
        country,
        crr_state,
        institution,
        fac_dept,
        current_status,
        year_entry,
        matric_number,
        student_status,
        edu_level,
        applying_as,
        team_members: {
          memberFullname1,
          memberEmail1,
          memberPhone1,
          memberFullname2,
          memberEmail2,
          memberPhone2,
          memberFullname3,
          memberEmail3,
          memberPhone3,
          memberFullname4,
          memberEmail4,
          memberPhone4,
          memberFullname5,
          memberEmail5,
          memberPhone5,
        },
        idea_grant,
        category,
        area_of_interest,
        idea_summary,
        formStatus,
        video_url,
        id: user._id,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          firstname: "",
          lastname: "",
          middlename: "",
          gender: "",
          dob: "",
          phone: "",
          email: "",
          country: "",
          crr_state: "",
          current_status: "",
          institution: "",
          fac_dept: "",
          year_entry: "",
          matric_number: "",
          student_status: "",
          edu_level: "",
          applying_as: "",
          team_members: {
            memberFullname1: "",
            memberEmail1: "",
            memberPhone1: "",
            memberFullname2: "",
            memberEmail2: "",
            memberPhone2: "",
            memberFullname3: "",
            memberEmail3: "",
            memberPhone3: "",
            memberFullname4: "",
            memberEmail4: "",
            memberPhone4: "",
            memberFullname5: "",
            memberEmail5: "",
            memberPhone5: "",
          },
          idea_grant: "",
          category: "",
          area_of_interest: "",
          idea_summary: "",
          video_url: "",
          id,
          textChange: "Application submitted for review ",
          formStatus: "Pending application",
        });
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          textChange: "Application Submitted",
          formStatus: "Application Pendig",
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          firstname: "",
          lastname: "",
          middlename: "",
          gender: "",
          dob: "",
          phone: "",
          email: "",
          country: "",
          crr_state: "",
          current_status: "",
          institution: "",
          fac_dept: "",
          year_entry: "",
          matric_number: "",
          student_status: "",
          edu_level: "",
          applyisng_as: "",
          team_members: {
            memberFullname1: "",
            memberEmail1: "",
            memberPhone1: "",
            memberFullname2: "",
            memberEmail2: "",
            memberPhone2: "",
            memberFullname3: "",
            memberEmail3: "",
            memberPhone3: "",
            memberFullname4: "",
            memberEmail4: "",
            memberPhone4: "",
            memberFullname5: "",
            memberEmail5: "",
            memberPhone5: "",
          },
          idea_grant: "",
          category: "",
          area_of_interest: "",
          idea_summary: "",
          video_url: "",
          formStatus: "",
          id,
        });
        setFormData({ ...formData, textChange: err.response.data.message });
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStates = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        "https://nigerian-states-info.herokuapp.com/api/v1/states"
      );
      setStates(result.data.data);
    };
    fetchStates();
  }, [user]);
```

As you can see above in the useEffect, first I defined a function that check if the user exist outside the ueEffect which the chechking is true but can update when a user login, the I thought of using useState to passed that value but still, it did not works. Please any suggestion on how to update my component when the signin went through ?
Please help.....

Comment: just move the redirection code from the useEffect to the api success response callback just after you set the data in localStorage

Answer (score 2):

Your `useEffect` only runs once and that is right after the component has been loaded. Right now its not aware of any other changes since you have given empty dependency array to it.
To suggest a solution in your case, why don't you just call

```
history.push("/application")
```

after you set the data to localStoare? That is after the line

```
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(res.data));
```

and remove the `useEffect`

Comment: how do I used the localStorage to puplate the user data in the next page. it's a form page 
 like an application. sinece the data got store in the local storage. should I used the useEffect or how and if you want me tom show the component that would be alright @Vishnu Sajeev.

Comment: Since the data is already in localStorage, when the new component loads you can use `useEffect` to get the data and store it in state and then use it

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Force Update by React hooks.

Declare `const [render, setRerender] = useState(false);`

then call the following when you want to update the UI, `setRerender(!rerender);`